# Change size of CanvasGradient after creation?

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts

I'm using a CanvasGradient as a background on a line chart, but I can't figure out how to resize the gradient without redrawing the whole chart.

Is it possible to resize a CanvasGradient after it has been created?

Comment: No you can not resize it after it has been rendered. You can resize it after it has been created by changing the current transform, but you will have to rerender it.

Comment: Also note that ChartJS will resize the canvas if it determines it's necessary to render the chart -- a somewhat aggravating "feature" of ChartJS. Ditto @Blindman67's info that the canvas element  cannot be resized without auto-clearing its existing drawings. Perhaps create a second canvas and layer it underneath the ChartJS canvas. That way you can resize + re-gradient as needed without disturbing the ChartJS.